# Twitter Button not counting tweets when query string added

Tags: twitter, query-string

This page has a few tweets counted for it:

http://development-area.com/stackoverflow/

however, as soon as I add a query string, the count goes to zero.

http://development-area.com/stackoverflow/?omg=lolz

Can anyone see why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it. I simply have to add the data-counturl attribute and hard code the URL, instead of relying on the page URL.